# NextJS App hosted on Vercel - having error with 'pdf2json' library

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel, pdf2json

When I run my Nextjs program locally, it runs fine. I've just recently hosted it on Vercel and I'm getting

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/task/node_modules/pdf2json/base/shared/util.js'

From a call to a route using the [pdf2json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2json) library. I've turned to a couple of GitHub comments and tried everything I could find but I think I'm just not understanding why it can't find that file.
I would appreciate any insight. Thank you!

I've tried:

- https://github.com/modesty/pdf2json/issues/161
- https://github.com/vercel/ncc/issues/349